# Google content wider than screen if I set swiper image height to 100%

Tags: html, css

New to webdevelopment here. I was testing my first website([www.finecrete.com.pk](http://www.finecrete.com.pk)) on the google url inspection tool. The tool would constantly say that the content is wider than the screen. Checked by removing different parts of my html and narrowed it down to my swiperjs gallery.

The HTML for the swiper section is:

```
<div class="fourth-content-gallery">
    <div class="bar-gallery">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-content">
              <img
                src="./assets/images/pictures/img_Privatewing.webp"
                alt="picture of capri tile installed in new private wing"
                class="swiper-image"
              />
              <div class="text-overlay">
                Our capri tiles at the new private wing.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div lazy="true" class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-content">
              <img
                src="./assets/images/pictures/img_walkfarm.webp"
                alt="picture of pavers karachi"
                class="swiper-image"
              />
              <div class="text-overlay">
                City pavers installed in DHA farmhouse.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div lazy="true" class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-content">
              <img
                src="./assets/images/pictures/img_Kathore.webp"
                alt="picture of capri tile at a farmhouse"
                class="swiper-image"
              />
              <div class="text-overlay">
                Capri tile with black inlays at a farmhouse.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div lazy="true" class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-content">
              <img
                src="./assets/images/pictures/img_Classico.webp"
                alt="picture of classico paver at DHA city"
                class="swiper-image"
              />
              <div class="text-overlay">
                Classico paver installed at gateway park.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div lazy="true" class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-content">
              <img
                src="./assets/images/pictures/img_blendtile.webp"
                alt="picture of blend tiles at home"
                class="swiper-image"
              />
              <div class="text-overlay">
                Our blend tiles at a home patio.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div lazy="true" class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-content">
              <img
                src="./assets/images/pictures/img_Saimaboul.webp"
                alt="picture of pavers with quadra edging"
                class="swiper-image"
              />
              <div class="text-overlay">
                Our pavers with quadra edging at Saima Boulevard.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div lazy="true" class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-content">
              <img
                src="./assets/images/pictures/img_HMR.webp"
                alt="picture of pavers installed at HMR waterfront"
                class="swiper-image"
              />
              <div class="text-overlay">
                HMR Waterfront paved with city paver.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-text bar-rhs">
      <h2>
        Picture perfect <span class="highlight-head">hardscapes.</span>
      </h2>
      <p>
        Mix our wide range of concrete products to get the perfect result
        you want. All of our products are designed to compliment each other,
        the capri tile seamlessly integrates with the casado, the roman
        classic and the maple leaf work as a standalone focus drivers and
        the city paver works with everything else.
      </p>
      <p>
        Browse through our selected gallery of product installations from
        various customers in Karachi and Sindh.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
  .fourth-content-gallery {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 75% 20%;
  margin: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.swiper {
  height: 70vh;
  width: 95%;
  min-width: 580px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-slide {
  background: #000000;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

After playing around with the CSS i got it to "work" but not exactly as it should.
I want to set the image height to 100% instead of auto, so that the image occupies the entire height of the swiper. Right now if you go on the website, it appears to work properly only because I've reduced the height of the .swiper to 70vh on large screens and 32vh on mobiles.

If i set the height to 100% everything works fine on all screen sizes, but then i get the error on google inspector. I cant figure out whats wrong and how to go about fixing it.

I've tried resizing the images so they fit the gallery on all screen sizes, I've tried removing the text-overlays, I've tried changing the CSS a million times but anything that fixes the image size problem ultimately breaks the google inspector test.